# file with multiple headers to dataframe with melt

Tags: python, pandas

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+----+
|      |      |      |      | USD  | EUR  | JPY  | RUP |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      | Case | Cons | Case | Case|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      | High | Low  | CWM  | AEP |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Owner| OPS  | VH   |Delta|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| V1   |  V2  | V3   | V4   | V5   | V6   | V7   | V8  |
| V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | V5a  | V6a  | V7a  | V8a | 
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

as requested here is the sample data as output by `df.to_dict()`:

```
{('Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2', 'Year'): {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2020, 5: 2020, 6: 2020, 7: 2020, 8: 2020, 9: 2020, 10: 2020, 11: 2020, 12: 2020, 13: 2020, 14: 2020, 15: 2020, 16: 2020, 17: 2020, 18: 2020, 19: 2020, 20: 2020, 21: 2020, 22: 2020, 23: 2020, 24: 2020, 25: 2020, 26: 2020, 27: 2020, 28: 2020, 29: 2020, 30: 2020, 31: 2020, 32: 2020, 33: 2020, 34: 2020, 35: 2020, 36: 2020, 37: 2020, 38: 2020, 39: 2020, 40: 2020, 41: 2020, 42: 2020, 43: 2020, 44: 2020, 45: 2020, 46: 2020, 47: 2020}, ('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2', 'Month'): {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 20: 1, 21: 1, 22: 1, 23: 1, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 1, 28: 1, 29: 1, 30: 1, 31: 1, 32: 1, 33: 1, 34: 1, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1, 41: 1, 42: 1, 43: 1, 44: 1, 45: 1, 46: 1, 47: 1}, ('Unnamed: 2_level_0', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2', 'Day'): {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 20: 1, 21: 1, 22: 1, 23: 1, 24: 2, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2, 28: 2, 29: 2, 30: 2, 31: 2, 32: 2, 33: 2, 34: 2, 35: 2, 36: 2, 37: 2, 38: 2, 39: 2, 40: 2, 41: 2, 42: 2, 43: 2, 44: 2, 45: 2, 46: 2, 47: 2}, ('Unnamed: 3_level_0', 'Unnamed: 3_level_1', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2', 'Hour'): {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 0, 25: 1, 26: 2, 27: 3, 28: 4, 29: 5, 30: 6, 31: 7, 32: 8, 33: 9, 34: 10, 35: 11, 36: 12, 37: 13, 38: 14, 39: 15, 40: 16, 41: 17, 42: 18, 43: 19, 44: 20, 45: 21, 46: 22, 47: 23}, ('USD', 'Cons', 'very high', 'Hub1'): {0: 23.06, 1: 21.49, 2: 21.73, 3: 21.58, 4: 21.67, 5: 22.78, 6: 27.15, 7: 26.09, 8: 26.23, 9: 28.21, 10: 29.21, 11: 31.97, 12: 30.45, 13: 30.45, 14: 30.45, 15: 29.14, 16: 28.28, 17: 26.35, 18: 26.32, 19: 27.01, 20: 26.34, 21: 28.22, 22: 27.77, 23: 26.94, 24: 24.16, 25: 22.74, 26: 22.67, 27: 22.67, 28: 22.74, 29: 23.14, 30: 27.81, 31: 27.87, 32: 28.05, 33: 27.91, 34: 32.66, 35: 35.14, 36: 33.32, 37: 36.17, 38: 38.33, 39: 31.75, 40: 30.9, 41: 26.36, 42: 27.17, 43: 28.17, 44: 26.17, 45: 26.5, 46: 28.95, 47: 26.94}, ('EUR', 'Case', 'CWM', 'Hub2'): {0: 18.59, 1: 18.32, 2: 18.32, 3: 18.32, 4: 18.32, 5: 19.19, 6: 22.57, 7: 25.38, 8: 25.53, 9: 25.9, 10: 26.47, 11: 26.47, 12: 26.09, 13: 25.59, 14: 25.35, 15: 24.97, 16: 24.22, 17: 25.22, 18: 25.49, 19: 26.19, 20: 25.63, 21: 25.1, 22: 21.93, 23: 19.61, 24: 19.4, 25: 18.75, 26: 18.85, 27: 18.75, 28: 18.88, 29: 19.41, 30: 23.97, 31: 27.07, 32: 27.23, 33: 29.21, 34: 30.49, 35: 28.52, 36: 27.49, 37: 26.93, 38: 26.71, 39: 25.76, 40: 25.24, 41: 25.67, 42: 26.72, 43: 27.98, 44: 26.73, 45: 25.97, 46: 22.34, 47: 19.47}, ('USD', 'Cons', 'Ventyx', 'Hub3'): {0: 19.78, 1: 20.96, 2: 21.58, 3: 21.5, 4: 21.27, 5: 22.59, 6: 26.22, 7: 26.78, 8: 26.78, 9: 26.97, 10: 26.97, 11: 26.97, 12: 26.53, 13: 26.34, 14: 26.5, 15: 26.22, 16: 25.6, 17: 26.5, 18: 26.74, 19: 27.44, 20: 26.87, 21: 26.5, 22: 23.2, 23: 23.58, 24: 22.74, 25: 22.31, 26: 22.27, 27: 22.27, 28: 22.74, 29: 22.84, 30: 27.79, 31: 31.63, 32: 29.6, 33: 29.25, 34: 30.53, 35: 28.51, 36: 27.48, 37: 26.97, 38: 26.74, 39: 26.53, 40: 26.5, 41: 26.92, 42: 28.89, 43: 30.24, 44: 28.38, 45: 27.38, 46: 24.39, 47: 23.2}}
```

That is about as good a representation as I can make for this file.

Columns 1-4 have a single header Columns 5-N (yes N, because we don't know how many) have 4 headers.

The dataframe needs to look like this:

```
 +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | NCol1| NCol2|NCol3 | NCol4| Col9 |
 +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
 | V1   |  V2  | V3   | V4   | USD  | Case | High | Owner| V5   |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | USD  | Case | High | Owner| V5a  |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | EUR  | Cons | Low  | Ops  | V6   |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | EUR  | Cons | Low  | Ops  | V6a  |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | JPY  | Case | CWM  | VH   | V7   |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | JPY  | Case | CWM  | VH   | V7a  |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | RUP  | Case | AEP  | Delta| V8   |
 | V1a  |  V2a | V3a  | V4a  | RUP  | Case | AEP  | Delta| V8a  |
 +------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+------+-------+
```

So essentially pivot the 5th through N column headers into new columns where each row of data is aligned with the first 4 columns and the headers the values were originally under.

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,header=[0,1,2,3])
df.melt(var_name=['a','b','c','d'], value_name='e')
```

Also:

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['Year','Month','Day','Hour'], col_level=3)
```

And :

```
df2 = df.stack().stack().stack().stack()
```

That last one is ver close, but it does the first 4 columns

However that doesn't work as it gives me just col1 and col2.

Comment: can you do a df.to_dict() and paste the outcome? that is read the csv and output it as to dict and share it. it should be easier to work with than what you have currently provided

Comment: Let me see about creating some same information that matches better and post it.

Comment: Only thing I worry about when providing that dict is that is a small sample and the dataframe can have an unknown amount of columns.

Comment: Did you not read the I tried part?

Comment: here I will add 10 more things I have tried that also don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I am shooting in the dark but this is what i could pull out. lemme know if it is not what you want. if it isn't, kindly post a sample output based on the dict you posted so others can butt in. and i'll gladly delete this hack

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)

df.columns =df.columns.to_flat_index()

df.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df.columns]

df = df.melt(id_vars=['Unnamed: 0_level_0_Unnamed: 0_level_1_Unnamed: 
             0_level_2_Year',
    'Unnamed: 1_level_0_Unnamed: 1_level_1_Unnamed: 1_level_2_Month',
    'Unnamed: 2_level_0_Unnamed: 2_level_1_Unnamed: 2_level_2_Day',
    'Unnamed: 3_level_0_Unnamed: 3_level_1_Unnamed: 3_level_2_Hour'])

df.columns = [i.split('_')[-1] for i in df.columns]

pd.concat([df,df.variable.str.split('_',expand=True)],axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried something similar.  your code results in `"The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['Unnamed: 0_level_0_Unnamed: 0_level_1_Unnamed:0_level_2_Year']"`

Comment: Your code worked without `df2.columns = [i.split('_')[3] for i in df.columns]`

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Cheers