# Unable to melt dataframe with multiple headers whose values are not static

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt, data-wrangling

I am trying to convert values in the headers of the third and fourth columns as rows

```py
df = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx", sheet_name = 0, header=[14,15,16,17,18])

df = df.melt(col_level=0, id_vars = ["Unnamed: 0_level_0", "Unnamed: 0_level_1"], var_name='Region', value_name='Value')
print(df.columns)
```

input file data

|  | Country1 | Country1 | Country1 | Country | Country1 | Country2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2000 |
|  | Type1 | Type1 | Type2 | Type1 | Type2 | Type1 |
|  | jan | feb | feb | apr | jan | feb |
|  | unit1 | unit2 | unit2 | unit1 | unit1 | unit1 |
| xyz1 | xyzdetails | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| xyz2 | xyzdetails | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| xyz3 | xyzdetails | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| xyz4 | xyzdetails | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| xyz5 | xyzdetails | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| xyz6 | xyzdetails | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| xyz7 | xyzdetails | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| xyz8 | xyzdetails | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

expected output:

|  |  | country | Year | Type | Month | Unit | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz1 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 1 |
| xyz2 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 2 |
| xyz3 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 3 |
| xyz4 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 4 |
| xyz5 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 5 |
| xyz6 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 6 |
| xyz7 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 7 |
| xyz8 | xyzdetails | Country1 | 2000 | Type1 | jan | unit1 | 8 |

Comment: if you can, share the excel file, with your expected output dataframe. It is possible that you are not reading in the file properly. Alternatively, you can share a reproducible sample of your dataframe, along with an expected output

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to load an excel sample for better clarify . but the file has been read correctly . I have been trying to convert data from 15th to 19th row as a individual column keeping the values present from row 20 as it is. and also I am trying to skip first 14 rows and retain column1 and column2 as it is

Comment: it's very hard to help with the information given. Can you supply sample in and output in proper formatting or rewrite the question indicating your desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks @Timus for formatting the table structure.

Comment: Thanks to @sammywemmy. I was able to resolve the issue based on your answer for one of the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59852608/8610293